# Is aspnetdb.mdf ever meant to be used in a production online web application?

Tags: asp.net, security

Is the generated aspnetdb.mdf ever meant to be used online?  It has been a while since I looked at it, but from what I remember the generated username database could only be configured and maintained locally within your visual studio environment.  Is this still true?  Does anyone use this online for big apps?

EDIT:

I ask because all the examples I see just use the built in VS tools to build the example database, but I haven't found where they did a "real" one online.

EDIT:

It just seemed like a big let down to know that you could create this username/password db for use in your projects and then find out you really can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simply a SQL Express db. You can certainly maintain the membership information in aspnetdb.mdf through your own administration pages if you want to.

As a matter of fact, if you're going to use SQL Express as your database (very limited scenarios where this would be appropriate) you could add the rest of your tables/sprocs to aspnetdb.mdf and use just the one db rather than using aspnetdb.mdf for membership and creating another one for your other needs.

[This article](http://www.devx.com/MicrosoftISV/Article/38728) has information on the limitations of sql express as well as links to the featureset ([2005](http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/compare-features.aspx), [2008](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/editions-compare.aspx))

Basically the limitations are:

1. Only 1 CPU. If a system has more than 1 SQL Express 2008 will still run but limit itself to 1 CPU.
2. RAM: 1 GB. More RAM can exist, but again SQL Express 2008 will only make use of a maximum 1 GB.
3. Max Database Size: 4 GB

Answer (score 1):

> configured and maintained locally
>   within your visual studio environment.
>   Is this still true

No, it's not true.

You can use aspnet_regsql scripts to generate all the required tables/scripts/views in your database, and you don't have to use the aspnetdb.mdf.

After all, it's just a bunch of database objects required by the membership/security api.